# OpenShift3 API Refresh Token

Tags: api, openshift, access-token

I'm looking into OpenShift3 API to refresh a authenticated token.

I've authenticated and have a existing token but would need to refresh it every 30mins.

From the documentation - https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/rest_api/openshift_v1.html#create-a-oauthaccesstoken

It requires a v1.OAuthAccessToken object but everything is optional, calling it with a empty object returns with this error:

```
{ kind: 'Status',
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  metadata: {},
  status: 'Failure',
  message: 'User "admin01" cannot create oauthaccesstokens at the cluster scope',
  reason: 'Forbidden',
  details: { kind: 'oauthaccesstokens' },
  code: 403 }
```

Anyone any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenShift does not support refresh tokens at this time.  If you are looking for a long lived token create a service account and use the service account token to grant access.

Comment: Updated output as I realize typos in my code.

Comment: @Clayton do you mean that service account can create a access token as another existing account? I would want to use a existing account access token to access/action upon it's own items rather than a service account.